# Flutter Flame Game how to add projectile?

Tags: flutter, flame

I've added bullets that my character can shoot but despite making their starting position the same as my character they seem to be rendered to the bottom left/right underneath my level. The bullets also exhibit unexpected behavior like changing position when my character does(note I purposefully slowed speed of bullets but they are moving horizontally as expected.), see Gif:[image]

To create the bullet I made a simple class that extends SpriteAnimationComponent (Maybe this is not ideal way to create the Bullet class, please advise me if I'm mistaken):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flame/collisions.dart';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:marvington_game/game.dart';

class Bullet extends SpriteAnimationComponent with HasGameRef<Gain>, CollisionCallbacks {
  double xdir;
  Bullet({super.position, super.size, required this.xdir});
  final double _speed = 20;
  final Vector2 velocity = Vector2.zero();

  FutureOr<void> onLoad() {
    debugMode = true;

    animation = _createSpriteAnimation();
    add(CircleHitbox(position: position, collisionType: CollisionType.active));
    return super.onLoad();
  }

  void update(double dt) {
    velocity.x = xdir * _speed;
    position.x += velocity.x * dt;
    super.update(dt);
  }

  void onCollision(Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints, PositionComponent other) {
    removeFromParent();
    super.onCollision(intersectionPoints, other);
  }

  SpriteAnimation _createSpriteAnimation() {
    return SpriteAnimation.fromFrameData(
      game.images.fromCache("Marvington/Marv Bullet.png"),
      SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
        amount: 1,
        stepTime: 0.11,
        textureSize: Vector2.all(16),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then I add it to the game in my player class when a certain key is pressed calling this function:

```
  void _shoot() {
    Vector2 pos = Vector2(position.x, position.y);
    Bullet b = Bullet(xdir: scale.x, position: pos);
    add(b);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a component as a child to another component it is rendered in relation to that component. So what you want to do here is add the projectiles to the `world` (or whatever parent your player has) and with the same starting position as the player.

```dart
  void _shoot() {
    Bullet b = Bullet(xdir: scale.x, position: position);
    parent?.add(b);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly (had to use ```parent!.add(b)```)